# Onchange demora a receber novo valor no input

Tags: react

Estou criando um pequeno formulário apenas para teste, onde o usuário digita seu nome no campo e após isso ha uma verificação se o nome encontrado esta salvo em um objeto chamado `obj`, mas depois que digito um novo valor no campo de texto não reconhece que entrou um novo valor, so depois que clico duas vezes atualiza o valor. Não entendo a demora, pensava que `onChange` reconheceria de imediato a mudança no input.

```jsx
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'
import obj from '../Banco_de_Dados/Banco';

export default function Form() {

  
  const [Valor, setValor] = useState([])
  const [tempValor, settempValor] = useState("")
  const [banco] = useState(obj);

  const pegarvalor = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    
    setValor(tempValor);
    
    console.log(Valor)
   
    comparandoValor()
      
  }

  function comparandoValor() {
    if (banco[0].nome == Valor) {
      
      console.log("valido")
    } else {
      
      console.log("invalido")
    }
    
  }

  return (
    <>
    <h1>Faça seu login</h1>
      <p>Insira seus dados</p>
      <p>{tempValor}</p>

        <form onSubmit={pegarvalor}>

            <input type='text'
            placeholder='Digite seu nome'
            onChange={({target}) => settempValor(target.value)}> 
            </input>
            
        <button 
        type='button' 
        onClick={pegarvalor}>teste</button>
        </form>
        
    </>
  )
}


obj: import React from "react";

const obj = [
    {nome : "maria", chave : "1213"},
    {nome : "simone",chave : "1233"},
    {nome : "carlos",chave : "1273"}
    
];

export default obj;
```

Apenas estou verificando um `indice[0]`, mas teria como percorrer todos os indices para fazer a verificação certo? Deixar dinâmico. Seria correto um `forEach`?

Comment: No `input` já tenta fazer assim: `<input value={tempValor} onChange={({target}) => settempValor(target.value)}/>`   . E não use a close tag `</input>` em HTML o `<input>` é um [elemento vazio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element) que não pode ter nós filhos. Elementos vazios possuem apenas uma tag inicial e tags finais não devem ser especificadas.

Comment: eu entendo, obg pela dica. Mas o erro ainda persiste. Quando adiciono um novo valor ao input e clico em enter mostra o valor digitado anteriormente no console. So quando dou dois clicks no botao que atualiza o novo valor.